# Swing: Action for Ctrl+Number does not work properly if number is pressed on numpad

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

I have a JTabbedPane, which must switch tabs when Ctrl+Number is pressed (Ctrl+1 for the first tab). Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class NumberSwitchTryout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Switch between tabs on Ctrl+Number");
        JTabbedPane tabber = new JTabbedPane();
        tabber.add("First", new JTextField("First"));
        tabber.add("Second", new JTextField("Second"));
        tabber.add("Third", new JTextField("Third"));
        tabber.add("Fourth", new JTextField("Fourth"));
        JPanel enclosingPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        enclosingPanel.add(tabber);
        enclosingPanel.add(new JTextField("Field outside tabber"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.add(enclosingPanel);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ChangeTabAction act = new ChangeTabAction(tabber, i);
            KeyStroke stroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control " + (i + 1));
            enclosingPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(stroke, i);
            enclosingPanel.getActionMap().put(i, act);
        }
        frm.setSize(500, 500);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class ChangeTabAction extends AbstractAction {
        private JTabbedPane tabber;
        private int index;
        public ChangeTabAction(JTabbedPane aTabber, int anIndex) {
            tabber = aTabber;
            index = anIndex;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tabber.setSelectedIndex(index);
        }
    }
}
```

All works fine when a normal number key is pressed. But failed when the key is pressed on number block of keyboard. Some ideas, how to make it working also for the numpad (I need it because most of our customers primarily working with the numpad)?

Background: I have some JTabbedPane with the different number of tabs (but always less than 10). All these JTabbedPane are declared in a class (one JTabbedPane per instance of a class). This class has method `addTab(String name, Component tab)`. And when a tab is added I need to register a key action for switch to this tab in the enclosing panel. So I look now for a generic solution.

Comment: Might be a stupid suggestion, but have you got num lock disabled or enabled? Could be worth checking.

Comment: @James it's enabled by me and by our customers.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the numbers at the top of the keyboard and those on the numpad are different entities. For example, if using a keyboard listener, I believe for the standard two, it would be a KeyEvent.VK_2 and for the numpad KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2. Perhaps this may help you?

Comment: Oh... I'm stupid :(((. Thanks!

Comment: @James if you create a little answer, I will check it as correct.

Comment: Works fine for me, both the numbers across and the num pad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, but it may help guide you towards a solution.

If I remember correctly, the numbers at the top of the keyboard and those on the numpad are different entities. I will add an example below using a keyboard listener, which you may be able to integrate into your code.

For example:

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2)
    System.out.println("NUMPAD 2 pressed.");

else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2)
    System.out.println("Normal 2 pressed.");
```

Hope this helps.

Note: You can find the KeyEvent documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html